# django channels ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot find 'app' in ASGI_APPLICATION module

Tags: python, django, redis, channel

I am setting up channels asgi with Django. I have tried upgrading Django and Channels.

```
"Cannot find %r in ASGI_APPLICATION module %s" % (name, path)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot find 'app' in ASGI_APPLICATION module <MyApp>.routing
```

my routing config is as per the tutorial in mysite/routing

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
# (http->django views is added by default)
'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
    URLRouter(
        chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
    )
  ),
})
```

and the import statement that is supposed to just be simply

```
import chat.routing
```

my directory structure is exactly per the tutorial as well

with setting config

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'channels',
'chat',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

and

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'chat.routing.application'
```

Thanks

Comment: Add your routing config. Add relevant code snippets.

Answer (score 9):

I got this kind of error when running my [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)'s `routing.py` using [daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne) server.

```py
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

This is what documentation explain about [daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne) servers,

> Daphne is a HTTP, HTTP2 and WebSocket protocol server for ASGI and ASGI-HTTP, developed to power Django Channels.
>
> It supports automatic negotiation of protocols; there’s no need for URL prefixing to determine WebSocket endpoints versus HTTP endpoints.
>
> Note: Daphne 2 is not compatible with Channels 1.x applications, only with Channels 2.x and other ASGI applications. Install a 1.x version of Daphne for Channels 1.x support.

As you can see, we can use both `HTTP` and `WS`protocol through [daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne) server without using [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) server. What you can do is just add below line to top of your `routing.py` file.

```
from .wsgi import *
```

So now your `routing.py` file should be like this,

```py
# DockerDjangoNginx is my project name
# your routing.py file should be in this location where the wsgi.py file is placed
# DockerDjangoNginx/DockerDjangoNginx/routing.py

from .wsgi import *  # add this line to top of your code
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import comapp.routing as routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Now you can run your [daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne) server.

```
(venv) [root@t2mdocker]#daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 DockerDjangoNginx.routing:application
2019-05-30 03:33:06,390 INFO     Starting server at tcp:port=8000:interface=0.0.0.0
2019-05-30 03:33:06,391 INFO     HTTP/2 support enabled
2019-05-30 03:33:06,391 INFO     Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=0.0.0.0
2019-05-30 03:33:06,392 INFO     Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:8000
```

If you see something like this `HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)` when running [daphne](https://github.com/django/daphne) server, you can run `pip install -U Twisted[tls,http2]` to correct those errors.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you it took days and finally its done only with your guide

Comment: @Hamedio glad to hear that, happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this was the problem. Needed to add this asgi.py file next to wsgi.py

```
import os
import django

from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<myproj>.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

and start server with

```
(vEnv)$daphne <myproj>.asgi:application --port 8888
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.routing.application'

To

ASGI_APPLICATION = "myproject.asgi.application"

and issue will hopefully be solved, check the official channels site for more details (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it worked for me:

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

from chat import routing # This change

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
# (http->django views is added by default)
'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
    URLRouter(
        routing.websocket_urlpatterns   #This change
    )
  ),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings.py, you stated it included:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'chat.routing.application'
```

But chat is your added App, it should be the name of the django project itself, so in the tutorial you said you followed it should be something like:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.routing.application'
# or
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'core.routing.application'
```